# https to http in .htaccess with exceptions

Tags: linux, http, .htaccess, redirect, https

I've done enough research to figure out that to redirect sitewide all of my https pages to their http equivalent, I need to use this code...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

My issue is, there are a handle of pages that I still want to remain as https. For the sake of example, let's say I want page1.php, page2.php, and page3.php to REMAIN as .https, with everything else on the site redirecting. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force page1,2,3.php onto HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3)\.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

# Redirect other HTTPS requests to plain HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !(page1|page2|page3)\.php
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a total rookie with this. Does that replace my 3 redirect rules? Does everything have to go in a special order? Can you create a full .htaccess that summarizes everything? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider the above to be a complete .htaccess in the correct order already.  The top block replaces your three discreet rules with one regex.  I've also added `QSA` to the redirect flags to pass along any querystring.

Comment: That seems to cause an infinite loop for page1, page2, and page3.

Comment: Is the loop when https is on or off?  Comment out one block or the other to narrow it.  Or in the top block try changing the `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` to `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443`